# The application is in break mode after adding an appsettings section

Tags: c#

I get the following error message when I try to start my console application:

> The application is in break mode
>
> Your app has entered a break state, but no code is currently executing
>   that is supported by the selected debug engine (e.g. only native
>   runtime code is executing).

I have put a break point directly at the `Main` method and the code never gets there.

[image]

The only thing I have added is the following values to `App.config`:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="QueueItemsToGet" value="25" />
</appSettings>
```

If I check the exception in Output -> Debug or `Diagnostics Tools` I can only see this error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in NLog.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Unknown Module.
The type initializer for 'MyApp.Program' threw an exception.
```

However if I remove the `<appSettings>` section everything works, including Nlog.

Comment: The Output Window should show you an exception message to tell you exactly why the application is in break mode

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Nope, see my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have looked twice, it seems this error can occur if you add sections twice. In my case it was two definitions of `appSettings` since further down in the config the area was already added. I hope this can help someone else who makes the same mistake.

Comment: This is but one case. Any non-caught exception will present exactly the same behavior

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto This is true however I still think the answer can put people on the right track. I searched for this behavior and did not find a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

It was happening to me when I got an error on a static field initialization, for example, if you have a static Uri variable that is initialized with an invalid Uri (an empty string, in my case)